# Как подвал сделать ровным?

Tags: html, css

У меня сверху есть подвал, в свойствах css написано что он должен быть во всю горизонталь. Но у меня внизу браузера есть линия которая говорит о том что там `widht` больше ста. Что делать с этим?

И да, я вроде ровно расположил подвал а все таки отступ от лева и верха имеется, хотя там ничего не должно быть. Как исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="top"></div>
```

```
.top {
    background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.3);
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо удалить эту строку

```
width: 100%;
```

Comment: не помогло, не одна проблема не ушла

Comment: разобрался, спасибо